# How to create a TS fuction that will allow using Array.from() with a union type parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that is erroring out on Array.from(list);

> Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike'

how to solve this and make the function work for both types ?

```js
const reorderArray = (list: JSX.Element[] | number[], startIndex: number, endIndex: number): JSX.Element[] | number[] => {
    const result = Array.from(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
    return result;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't automatically distribute analysis over [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  So `Array.from(x)` where `x` is of type `T[] | U[]` is not going to be `T[] | U[]`; the best you could hope for would be a result of type `(T | U)[]`, and that would require specifying the type argument explicitly (because the compiler doesn't like to *synthesize* new union types during inference):

```
const reorderArray = (
    list: number[] | JSX.Element[], startIndex: number, endIndex: number
) => {
    const result = Array.from<number | JSX.Element>(list);
    // --------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // manually specify type argument
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
    return result;
}; 
// return type is (number | JSX.Element)[]
```

Maybe that's acceptable to you.

---

If not and you want to distinguish the `number[]` output from the `JSX.Element[]` output then the recommended approach is use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead of a union:

```
const reorderArray = <T extends JSX.Element | number>(
    list: T[], startIndex: number, endIndex: number
): T[] => {
    const result = Array.from(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
    return result;
};
```

Now the compiler understands all the operations in terms of the single generic type parameter `T`.  When you call the function with just `number[]` or just `JSX.Element[]`, the compiler can infer a type argument for `T` which will produce an array of a single narrowed type:

```
const n = [1, 2, 3];
const o = reorderArray(n, 1, 2);
// const o: number[]

const p = [<div />, <p />, <h1 />]
const q = reorderArray(p, 1, 2);
// const q: JSX.Element[]
```

This still won't give you a union output for a union input:

```
const r = Math.random() < 0.5 ? n : p;
const s = reorderArray(r, 1, 2); // error, just like original Array.from error
const t = reorderArray<number | JSX.Element>(r, 1, 2);
// const t: (number | JSX.Element)[] // array of unions, not union of arrays
```

but if you plan to call `reorderArray()` only on arrays of a known element type (and not a union of array types) then it doesn't matter.

---

If you *need* to have the output be a union of arrays, then things get hairier.  Ultimately the language does not support *correlated union types* very well.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The approaches to deal with that are usually either to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.ht) and move on:

```
const reorderArray2 = (
    list: number[] | JSX.Element[], startIndex: number, endIndex: number
): number[] | JSX.Element[] => {
    const result = Array.from<number | JSX.Element>(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
    return result as number[] | JSX.Element[]; // <-- assert
};
```

or write redundant code to force the compiler to deal with cases:

```
const reorderArray3 = (
    list: number[] | JSX.Element[], startIndex: number, endIndex: number
): number[] | JSX.Element[] => {
    if (list.every((i): i is number => typeof i === "number")) {
        const result = Array.from(list);
        const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
        result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
        return result;
    } else {
        const result = Array.from(list);
        const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
        result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
        return result;
    }
};
```

or refactor to a particular flavor of generics as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) which is a lot of hard-to-explain hoop-jumping:

```
interface TypeMap {
    n: number;
    e: JSX.Element
}
type ArrayType<K extends keyof TypeMap> = { [P in K]: Array<TypeMap[P]> }[K]
const reorderArray4 = <K extends keyof TypeMap>(
    list: ArrayType<K> & {}, startIndex: number, endIndex: number
): ArrayType<K> & {} => {
    const result = Array.from(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
    return result;
};
const reorderArray5 = reorderArray4<keyof TypeMap>
// const reorderArray5: (
//   list: number[] | JSX.Element[], 
//   startIndex: number, 
//   endIndex: number
// ) => number[] | JSX.Element[]
```

That last function is exactly what you asked for, but the procedure for getting the compiler to follow the logic is so tortured that I wouldn't recommend it unless your use cases require it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Io4AowE7o5CRm6oKwPQURFBq7XSCmg2wcFEGblGeXPTwykSoJVmzVYfVd-u68HO+jRIj7-pHzC6hgaJ2w7TomE3X5r2tAExDaJovx-Gk-2qAC2y0ZxJTJQkKSCVUwmwyIYnDTQdGQltnwcYYEmSNoGRFFlryKHAQFvCkHxQ1sX3gnUPz5C4tWGQ1tiVfYJRxBYfFWHjFTFUSVRCNUJw1XotWkvV7keeiUEhRDSKhJ9AO0E1KBMuiNy3Vk7RglF4OIqAkP01D7CxTDpTs3CFPwn8iIIkj2PIwyqLpNpgEwUR4LMJABigHgRBEYAqTgYAkp0u9aRgHgwDdMLksEPK4AAIh-AroliGi2h5Tt6LyRj2U5Zp5Qq3j4H5FTBkEmS9gOVzJNlHibiZcZZIOI5FLORk2u1RqKtuDShJeFFXlBKQ6CQYKmua+aL1ZJiR246baOjVrBQ6wbRS6sTcXxKSDoVM6RJGvCTiUibBX6u79U0s7ptech3koYB7DYTB0DWoFMqQXtY3KiQaDs6akCbDiKL+8gMqyuBWXBrKSgAaVBbxwS8SEAGskB4CAwuxyGUDABJhESLoAAUkseXGtAUVlgQhqGNCZrQEleDR2dA74IO3XgABYATxgmieYUnycpuBqah5E4LRTnr2pvGEgAMiSV4MPEqUvLvDysO8xKsYh3W4ANxIlsEaj6WjarMdq5j6qA6aGWOgTXSNB7Lok565RRTrlVG3rxv4q5ptmg0RWMsyrwKGd1zTqWSjJimqZ52m4nIQNNvAizrynBQxBLiRbN8+y9P-TjKOcYugwkHqlncuA28kaOu-r3vYmd+uHKbiiQPIGgUFsSZQbgEx1okM04ytGt7UdV3OxdTPxdZSXvTfaaS+dOz20OztYwtBMk3zdNMzTQFc3zQsL86Utd-LgoD6rWU-WP+sJYkYBTQpQN+8A1yXj3teA+e4-41nWH9IAA)